# Finding correlation coefficient of two dependent random variables

Tags: correlation, covariance

I know when there are two independent random variables X and Y, the correlation coefficient is
[image: formula]

But what if the two random variables are dependent, for example, Y-X and X+Y, how can I represent them in the form of E[X], E[Y], Var[X], and Var[Y]?

Comment: The correlation coefficient tells you if the variables are dependent or not; the formula as being the covariance scaled by the standard deviations is the same. (for example, If they are completely dependent then the magnitude of the correlation coefficient will be one)

Comment: If there are two _independent_ random variables in the _probabilistic_  sense (meaning that their _joint_ distribution factors into the product of their individual (a.k.a. marginal) distributions, then their correlation coefficient is $0$, no ifs ands or buts. That is, cov$(XY) = 0$. The formula that you have written down gives the correlation coefficient of two _arbitrary_ random variables without any attention paid as to whether they are independent or not, The formula applies universally and evaluates to $0$ whenever $X$ and $Y$ are _uncorrelated_ including as a special case _independent_.